# how to remove comments syntax only?

Tags: perl

I want collect all tags in from XML file. How can I remove comments syntax only?

XML File:

```
<xml>
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Holt</surname>
<given-names> Maurice<!--<xref ref-type="fn" rid="fnI_1"><sup>1</sup></xref>--></given-names>
</name>
</contrib>
</contrib-group>
</xml>
```

I need output as:

```
<xml>
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Holt</surname>
<given-names> Maurice<xref ref-type="fn" rid="fnI_1"><sup>1</sup></xref></given-names>
</name>
</contrib>
</contrib-group>
</xml>
```

How can I remove comments.. without remove contains?

script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

open(my $output , '>', "split.xml") || die "can't open the Output $!\n";
my $xml = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { xref => sub{comments => 'drop'} } );
$xml->parsefile("sample.xml");
$xml->print($output);
```

I can't do it... How can I remove `<!-- -->` only without remove contain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

open my $output , '>', 'split.xml' or die "Can't open: $!\n";
my $xml = XML::Twig->new( comments      => 'process',       # Turn on comment processing
                          twig_handlers =>
                              { '#COMMENT' => \&uncomment }
                        );
$xml->parsefile('sample.xml');
$xml->print($output);

sub uncomment {
    my ($xml, $comment) = @_;
    $comment->set_outer_xml($comment->text);                # Replace the comment with its contents.
}
```

Comment: It can't process this script, some came errors during compile so please if any other way..?

Comment: @user1811486: Please describe the errors you are getting. What version of Perl are you using? Is it just that you need to install `XML::Twig`?

Comment: I am currently using 5.8 perl version, and then XML::Twig also installed and then errors are "can't locate object method 'set_outer_xml'" how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @user1811486: Upgrade XML::Twig.

Comment: Thank to all it work well, comments => 'drop', am using this, perfectly working..